# Why some "Startup Programs" not starting at Windows startup?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10-preview

*Using Windows 10 preview version.*
Some of my start-up programs are not starting with Windows.

I can see them from the `Task Manager` and they are still showing `Enabled` at startup.

***Screenshot of Task Manager:***
[image: Startup programs]

But they are not actually starting with Windows. Each time the Windows boot up I need to start those needed programs manually.

I'm not sure if this is a bug of Win10 preview yet to be fixed or only I'm having this problem. Is there any ways to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Report the issue to `Realtek`.  I highly suspect this is a incapability problem with `Realtek` and Windows 10 more than anything

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, recently my Windows 10 updated to build 9879 and in this build OneDrive is updated. Now OneDrive is not starting with Windows either. It also shows a start-up entry in the Task Manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem starting a program in the startup folder at Windows startup](https://superuser.com/questions/199644/problem-starting-a-program-in-the-startup-folder-at-windows-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty weird but I just figured out the issue anyway.

I was using the *Start Screen* and some startup program was not starting with Windows.
Recently I switched to *Start Menu* and everything working perfectly.

[image]

I will report this issue too via *Windows Feedback*.

Comment: I do not have the "start menu" tab in the properties

Comment: @Ev0oD this setting was only available in the first preview builds and is removed in the final of Windows 10. The 1607 version also removed this dialog completely and moved it to the settings app