# App Windows 10 user Startup folder not starting on startup

Tags: windows-10, wamp

PC = Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

I have a WAMPServer shortcut placed in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

When I start Windows, WAMPServer does not start though.

If I look in Task Manager > Startup tab, WAMPServer is not listed.

Comment: maybe this will help [Start Menu instead of the Start Screen](http://superuser.com/questions/834135/why-some-startup-programs-not-starting-at-windows-startup)

Comment: use Autoruns to see all startup paths: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 Autoruns confirms I have the right folder to place shortcuts in, but only 2 of the 3 items listed in the folder in question are listed in Autoruns under that same folder. Why doesn't Autoruns display the WampServer shortcut?

Comment: That's strange. Try running [ProcMon](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/) and see what happens when "WampServer" is accessed. Keep Autoruns and ProcMon running (monitoring).. Refresh Autoruns and switch to ProcMon to see Wampserver entries.

Comment: Thanks @w32sh. If I open `ProcMon` and then WAMPServer from `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` the WAMPServer tray icon opens fine, and I see no problems in `ProcMon`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-elevated-shortcut-run-programs-bypass-uac): you can create an elevated shortcut for the program  that will allow you to bypass UAC Prompt and run the program without seeing the UAC Prompt in Windows. This is how you can do it.

1. Type Schedule Tasks in Start Search and hit Enter to open the Task Scheduler. Under Actions, click on Create Task
2. Under General tab, give the Task a name, say NoUAC1. Check Run with highest privileges.

   [image]
3. Under the Action tab, click on the New button and browse to the folder location of the program executable file and select it. The Action should be Start a program.

   [image]
4. Under the Settings tab, ensure that Allow task to be run on demand is checked.

[image]

5. Once all this is done, click on OK. A new Task will be created and you will be able to see it.
6. Now you will have to create a shortcut that will run this task.
7. Right-click on the desktop > New > Shortcut. In the the Create Shortcut wizard, type: `schtasks /run /TN "NoUAC1"`. Here NoUAC1 should be replaced with the name for the task that you have chosen. Click on Next and exit the wizard after it runs its course. Now you can give it an icon of your choice. To do so, right-click on the shortcut > Properties > Change icon. Browse to and select the icon you want. Now when you click this shortcut, you will be able to bypass the UAC Prompt.
8. Lastly, move this shortcut to `C:\Users\Yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`